# get a specific part of a string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have the following url. `http://domain.com/userfiles/dynamic/images/whatever_dollar_1318105152.png`
Everything in the url can change except the userfiles part and the last underscore. Basically I want to get the part of the url which is `userfiles/dynamic/images/whatever_dollar_` What is a good way to do this. I'm open or both JavaScript or php.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) in PHP to split an url in its various parts. Get the `path` part that is returned. It contains the path without the domain and the query string.

After that use [strrpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to find the last occurrance of the `_` within the path.

With [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) you can copy the first part of the path (up until the found `_`) and you're done.

Comment: Thanks Parse_url and PHP_URL_PATH are great. Why avoid using regex on urls ??? Seems more efficient to go regexp way.

Comment: regex is hardly ever more efficient on operations like this. Even if you can save yourself two or three lines of code on this problem, behind the screens you're starting a complex parser with numerous complex operations. And in these simple cases, regexes are often less readable than a couple of simple functions. But parsing urls with regex isn't as bad as parsing XML with regex. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could, with JavaScript, try:

```
var string = "http://domain.com/userfiles/dynamic/images/whatever_dollar_1318105152.png";

var newString = string.substring(string.indexOf('userfiles'),string.lastIndexOf('_'));
alert(newString); // returns: "userfiles/dynamic/images/whatever_dollar" (Without quotes).
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p2jKp/).

References:

- [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/subString).
- [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string is stored in $s, simply:

```
echo preg_replace('/.*(userfiles.*_).*/', '$1', $s);
```